# Is it possible to control cpu usage using Perl script in an idle machine?

Tags: perl

Is it possible to control cpu usage using Perl script in an idle machine?

like `some.pl 50` will consume 50% cpu, `some.pl 100` will consume 100% cpu usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, certainly it is possible. The following snippet calculates the percentage of processor load for a certain process **in an instant of time**. You probably first want to collect a certain number of values and average them for a smooth result.

Then simply, if the load is not high enough, tell the process to do work, if the load is too high, tell the process to pause work.

```
use constant UTIME => 13;
use constant STIME => 14;
use List::Util qw(sum);
use Time::HiRes qw(sleep);
use autodie qw(:all);

sub pidload {
    my ($pid) = @_;
    open my $pstat, '<', "/proc/$pid/stat";
    my @pstat = split ' ', <$pstat>;
    close $pstat;
    return $pstat[UTIME] + $pstat[STIME];
}

sub cpuload {
    open my $stat, '<', '/proc/stat';
    my @total = split ' ', <$stat>;
    close $stat;
    shift @total;
    return sum @total;
}

my ($pid) = @ARGV;
my $prev_cpu = cpuload;
my $prev_pid = pidload $pid;
while (1) {
    sleep 0.1;
    my $now_pid = pidload $pid;
    my $now_cpu = cpuload;
    printf "%.0f\n", 100*(($now_pid - $prev_pid) / ($now_cpu - $prev_cpu));
    $prev_cpu = $now_cpu;
    $prev_pid = $now_pid;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can't really tell a process how much CPU to use.  Instead, Unix allocates CPU using a priority system.  A high priority process will get more CPU time than a low priority one.  A low priority program is said to be [nice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_%28Unix%29).  You can control the priority of a program either by starting it with `nice`...

```
nice some.pl
```

Or by changing its priority while running with `renice`.

Windows does things differently.

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of any other processes, the running process will *always* get 100% unless it somehow puts itself to sleep periodically.

The only exception is multiprocessor machines, where a single-threaded process will only get 100% of *one* CPU core.

Answer (score 1):

You could crudely approximate this by something like

```
while (1) {
  if ($load < .5) {
    ... do something ...
  } else {
    sleep(10);
  }
}
```

You will probably need to run more than one of these in order to build up a sufficient load. The remaining challenge is how to "do something" which increases the load significantly, but runs only for a few seconds, and doesn't require a lot of memory or I/O (prime factorization?)

Answer (score 1):

if your OS has BSD layer just use: http://metacpan.org/pod/BSD::Resource

Answer (score -1):

Schwern has the right answer but if you want to try something I'd suggest you to use a separated thread that controls the plugin. In my opinion the actual code must not be touched. Instead I'll try to start a thread right at the beginning of the code that generates interrupts or events every time CPU goes over a certain level. That ofcourse is not easy at all and requires quite good knowledge of threads and (perhaps) semaphores. The only advantage is that if you write that subroutine well you can then use it in other plugins as well.